# Adding Venstar Add-a-wire to HVAC

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

I want to add 5th wire to my HVAC control with the Add-a-wire gizmo. Conceptually I understand their instruction diagram, but not completely when it comes to my HVAC layout. The HVAC is single stage forced gas heat and AC, currently controlled by a 4 wire thermostat. All very standard. But what do I do about the yellow wire? On my unit instead of being nicely tied to appropriately labeled terminals, the compressor is fed directly from thermostat's yellow wire. I was hoping someone experienced with these systems can dumb it down for me.

[image: HVAC diagram]
[image: wires at the HVAC]
[image: official add-a-wire diagram]

Comment: This appears to be a splitter in a plastic box. Simply jumping The Y and G terminal on the control board will do the same thing.

Comment: @Minc123 I don't think that's correct. Wouldn't jumping Y and G mean you couldn't run the fan without turning on the AC? My impression was that the two accessories communicate to determine whether or not to jump the wires. If the thermostat only turns on the fan, then it would not jump and the fan circuit would be completed over the blue wire?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll start by wiring the furnace and A/C as follows:

- `Red` from the furnace connects to `Red` from the thermostat cable and `Red` from the ADD-A-WIRE™ device.
- `White` from the furnace connects to `White` from the thermostat cable.
- `Green` from the furnace connects to `Green` from the ADD-A-WIRE™ device.
- `Blue` From the furnace connects to `White` from the A/C condensing unit, `Brown` from the ADD-A-WIRE™ device, and `Yellow` from the thermostat cable (this is `C`).
- `Red` from the A/C condensing unit connects to `Yellow` from the ADD-A-WIRE™ device.
- `Blue` from the ADD-A-WIRE™ device connects to `Green` from the thermostat cable.

[image: ADD-A-WIRE™ Furnace Wiring]

Next you'll connnect the wires to the thermostat as follows:

- `Red` connects to the `R` terminal.
- `White` connects to the `W` terminal.
- `Yellow` connects to the `C` terminal.
- `Green` connects to the ADD-A-WIRE™ Diode 'Y'.
- `Yellow` from the ADD-A-WIRE™ Diode 'Y' connects to the `Y` terminal.
- `Green` from the ADD-A-WIRE™ Diode 'Y' connects to the `G` terminal.

[image: ADD-A-WIRE™ Thermostat Wiring]

<sup>***WARNING:*** Modifying wiring for HVAC equipment could void the warranty, and/or cause damage, and/or injury, and/or death. Proceed at your own risk. Also, I don't know anything about the internal workings of this device. If this wiring causes any of the above mentioned problems, don't come looking for me. I'm just some random guy on the internet, who **you** chose to take advice from.</sup>

Comment: you are the best!! One followup question, am I reversing polarity on the A/C condensing unit with the new wiring? It seemed like existing red was ground and white was hot. Or is it 24vAC so doesn't matter? Thank you so much for posting an awesome diagram, which you are well known for :)

Comment: The wires going to the A/C unit should just be used to close the contactor, so it shouldn't matter which is which. If you'd like, you can connect the white to the yellow wire from the  ADD-A-WIRE™ device. Then you'll connect the red wire to blue, brown, and yellow bundle.